# How to show a widget throughout app based on condition?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I show a snackbar if network connectivity isn't there. I have created a separate stateful widget to check the connectivity and show the bar but I will have to add it to all the screens and so was wondering if there is a better way to include it in all the screens somehow.

Comment: Maybe implementing it with a Stack widget in the MaterialApp child would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I think you want to show the snack bar if the network is not available,?
to get the connectivity status you can use this,

```
var connectivityResult = await (new Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
    connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
} else {
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('SnackBar Demo'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text('No  Internet'),
    ), // You'll fill this in below!
  );
}
```

Comment: I was able to do this, now I want to implement this in all the screens of my app. I want to know a simple way to do that rather than adding it everywhere (even if it is just calling one constructor everywhere).

Comment: ok, cool then you have to create one global method like void _snackbar(BuildContext context){
... Snackbar...
}, and call it from didUpdateWidget() or, any other method where it gets called on every action., here you have to pass context and check connectivity status inside this method.

Comment: I have a StreamSubscription and have to set state every time connectivity changes. So I have created a stateful widget. Anyway, my point is to not call this widget from every screen. I was wondering if there is something like a theme, which can be applied throughout the app without me having to explicitly calling it from every screen.

Comment: Did you find any solution?